# Select cells on table by dragging on tablets

Tags: jquery

There were questions about it, and the solution seems to be simple... but how do I make it work on tablets?

```
$(function () {
  var isMouseDown = false,
    isHighlighted;
  $("#our_table td")
    .mousedown(function () {
      isMouseDown = true;
      $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
      isHighlighted = $(this).hasClass("highlighted");
      return false; // prevent text selection
    })
    .mouseover(function () {
      if (isMouseDown) {
        $(this).toggleClass("highlighted", isHighlighted);
      }
    })
    .bind("selectstart", function () {
      return false;
    })

  $(document)
    .mouseup(function () {
      isMouseDown = false;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Brv6J/3/

I tried to bind `touchstart` and `touchend` simultanously, but the problem seems to be `mouseover` event.

[This plugin](https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch) worked perfectly when using jQuery draggable, but doesn't seems to fix the problem in here.

Comment: Unless the "page" when rendered on a tablet is "fixed" such that it doesn't scroll then drag-n-drop doesn't work well.  You might be able to make a "long-press" trigger "selection" of the element AND force the "freezing" of the whole page to enable dragging (then undo once dragged to the desired destination) but I sense that this will be quite hacky... and error prone if not handled extremely well.

Comment: Not sure how that supposed to help me :)

Comment: What code did you use to bind to `touchstart`? It works okay for me using `.bind('touchstart', ...` as in: I don't get the error you've got in the console.

Comment: True, I tried `$obj.touchstart(function(){...` ... but that still doesn't fix it. Binding two additional events: `touchstart` and `touchend` doesn't make it work on ipad. Probably because `mouseover` event is not being used.

Comment: hmm yes I think you'll need an alternative approach for touch. You will probably need `touchstart` where your `mousedown` is, and then see whether `touchmove` triggers on elements you drag over (not sure about this step)? If it does, that's your equivalent of `mouseover`.

Comment: `touchmove` did not help... and there seems to be second problem... don't know why, I cannot select/deselect `a` and `b` on iPad... all other work by tapping it. That is really weird. When I tap `a`, facebook opens trying to create a post `Check out my fiddle`... when taping `b`, nothing happens.

Comment: @FlashThunder in short I guess I'm suggesting this will be complicated and possibly not worth the trouble.  Users will expect that swiping will scroll the page up and down (left/right) and drag-n-drop will not be expected.  I'd lean towards another method of sorting or showing the user a dedicated screen for the drag-n-drop that doesn't support scrolling.

Comment: @scunliffe: But how is it possible that plugins like the one I gave in question are working perfect with jQuery draggable and sortable without any unwanted scrolling?